# Use different variable depending on which view was used in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement

I'm using Mailboxer so that users can reply to posts in my site. There are two types of post models in my site which users might reply to, Requests and Offers.

Here is my messages controller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

    # GET /message/new
    def new
        @request = Request.find(params[:request])
        @message = current_user.messages.new
        @user = @request.user
    end

    def reply
        @conversation ||= current_user.mailbox.conversations.find(params[:id])
    end

    # POST /message/create
    def create
        @user = User.find(params[:user])
        @body = params[:body]
        @subject = params[:subject]
        current_user.send_message(@user, params[:body], params[:subject])
        flash[:notice] = "Message has been sent!"
        redirect_to :conversations
    end
end
```

In the `new` action, I'm using @request, but if I reply to an Offer post, I'll need to use an @offer variable. Is there a way I can use an if statement to choose between an @offer and @request depending on the view the `new` action is called from? Is this the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the most graceful thing in the world but something as simple as this should work.

```
if params[:request]
  @request = Request.find(params[:request])
else
  @offer = Offer.find(params[:offer])
end
```